# acessing an EditText in an Custom View of an AlertDialog

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-custom-view, android-alertdialog

How can i get the Text of an EditText, which is part of an layout for an Alert Dialog?

here the Code:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.From(this);
View view = li.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AlertDView1ET1TVhori, null);
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
adb.SetTitle(GetString(Resource.String.EMPSPSAlertTitleMany));
adb.SetView(view);
EditText adbText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtADV11Left);
```

and the Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/widget28">
  <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="test"
            android:id="@+id/txtADV11Left"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"/>
  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/lbADV11Right"
            android:text="Test"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is, that i don't even know how to access the EditText or the TextView in this layout. the last line of code won't find anything and at an later point i'll get an "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
because adbText is null.

and please don't complain about my weird names for layouts an stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access it until it is created / linked to the activity.

Instead you can try this:

```
EditText adbText = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtADV11Left);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [blog post about Dialogs on Mono for Android](http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/02/using-dialogs-in-mono-for-android.html), which you might find interesting. As Softlion answered, one way is to find it from your inflated view:

```
var customView = LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.AlertDView1ET1TVhori, null);

var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.SetView(customView);
builder.SetPositiveButton(Resource.String.dialog_ok, OkClicked);
builder.SetNegativeButton(Resource.String.dialog_cancel, CancelClicked);

//You should be able to access your EditText either here with:
var editText = customView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtADV11left);
```

You can also access the EditText in the EventHandlers like so:

```
private void OkClicked(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs args)
{
    var dialog = (AlertDialog) sender;
    var editText = (EditText)dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtADV11left);
}
```

Comment: and thanks to you too, i also will add your blog to my bookmarks, what i've seen there seemed to be really interesting